# PCRE Regex - replacing URLs in serialised strings

Tags: mysql, regex, serialization, grep, pcre

I'm migrating a few sites to different URLs, though I noticed that there's a lot of serialized entries in the database that contain the URLs. I've figured out a relatively simple regex to match a string that starts with the URL but this isn't always the case. Here's the regex I'm using.

```
s:(\d+?):\\\"(https?:\/\/)?example\.com
```

this matches perfectly fine against something like:
`s:15:\"http://example.com\"` but not if there's anything between it like: `s:15:\"foo bar example.com\"` 
(just examples in this case)
I tried adding in something like `.*?` here to match for characters in between, but then the regex catches too much.

tl;dr how do I stop regex catching too much. 
Here's the regex I'm using against a dummy sample.
https://regex101.com/r/3GRdLO/1

Comment: Try `[^"]*?` (any char but `"`, 0+ times, as few as possible) instead of `.*?`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/3GRdLO/2).

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thanks for looking into it. looks a little closer than it was before, though I think I'll still end up with an issue there with it not matching. i.e. if that URL was inside an <a> tag (often the case if the site was built with a page builder) e.g. https://regex101.com/r/3GRdLO/3

Comment: Try `s:(\d+):\\\"[^\\]*(?:\\(?!\")[^\\]*)*?(https?:\/\/)?example\.com`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/3GRdLO/5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match any text but an escape double quote in between `s:(\d+):\\\"` and the rest of the pattern:

```
s:(\d+):\\\"[^\\]*(?:\\(?!\")[^\\]*)*?(https?:\/\/)?example\.com
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3LE9Ye/1).

The pattern added is `[^\\]*(?:\\(?!\")[^\\]*)*?`:

- `[^\\]*` - any 0+ chars other than `\`
- `(?:\\(?!\")[^\\]*)*?` - 0+ occurrences, as few as possible, of the following sequence:

  - `\\` - a backslash
  - `(?!\")` - not followed with a double quote
  - `[^\\]*` - any 0+ chars other than `\`

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thanks for the help. Think I've got there in the end (mostly due to your help...) I added a quantifier around a chunk of the regex so it can also check for multiple occurrences in the same serialized string. You can see it here: https://regex101.com/r/3GRdLO/9

Comment: @Rhys My pattern provides the [expected results](https://regex101.com/r/3LE9Ye/2)